# mysql Database Schema for different group of user in same table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema, foreign-key-relationship

I have two type of user in my master table **Doctor** and **Hospital** both user has common fields like Name,Address,Contacts etc.

But there are some different fields which is connected by foreign key to this table
Like for **Doctor** it has

> one to one relation with specialization and department table

and for **Hospital**

> has one to one with service and one to many with facilities table

Now my question is What should be the database schema for this type of relation, At present I made **separate** table for both Doctor and Hospital but the fields like Name,Contact and Adreess repeating in both table.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Doctor and Hospital are both subclasses of some superclass, and the fields that repeat in both of them are attributes of that superclass.  Do some google searches with either of these two search terms:  "Generalization/Specialization" or "Class Table Inheritance".  That second term will show you some specific designs for implementing subtypes or subclasses in relational tables.

You might want to ask the question of in the Database Administrators area.  There is a tag called "subtypes" over there with one question in it.  It's asking the same thing you are, in a different case.